# Set AG filter before rows are rendered

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using [AG Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) to display client side data. There are some preset filters that I need to apply before rendering any data. I'm doing this by calling `setFilterModel` on the gridApi on the `gridReady` event, but this is too late. The data has already rendered at that point so I get all the data showing briefly before the filter is applied and rows are then removed again.

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    params.api.setFilterModel(this.filterModel);
}
```

Is there an event I can use, or a way to access the grid API to set the filter model before rendering any data?

I have created a Stackblitz demo showing the problem. The demo only shows a brief flicker, but it takes longer to refresh the data with custom renderers, more columns etc.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-set-initial-filter-state-so-64426323?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Thanks,

Comment: Please could you provide a stackblitz (or similar) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Hi @Fletch I have added a Stackblitz.

Comment: is there any specific requirement that you are setting row data in `onInit` and not in `gridReady`?

Comment: Only to simulate having lots of data before loading the grid. In the actual application it is the parent that generates the row data and passes it to the component using `@Input` but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onFirstDataRendered() method:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered()">
</ag-grid-angular>

private gridApi;
private gridColumnApi;

onGridReady(params: AgGridEvent) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
}

onFirstDataRendered() {
    this.gridApi.setFilterModel(this.filterModel);
}
```

Comment: The firstDataRendered event is fired after the gridReady event. Both events are emitted after the data is rendered.